# chartjs zoom not work with angular component

Tags: angular, chart.js, zooming

I want to draw a chart and be able to zoom on it. I'm working with angular 5. when I draw chart in index.html everything is good, see the chart and be able to zoom, but when I add my angular component in index.html, zoom is disabled. I saw that dozoom() function  in chartjs-plugin-zoom which is responsible for zoom isn't call anymore when angular component is added. any idea?

Comment: I have the same problem here. Did you solve it?